# Access token revocation implementation in OAuth 2 (Node js)

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, postman, access-token

I am using oAuth 2 package modified by him -> https://github.com/pedroetb/node-oauth2-server-mongo-example

I am stuck in the token revocation part. How to logout a user by calling revoke token?

```
var revokeToken = function(token, callback) {

    tokenModel.deleteOne({
        refreshToken: token.refreshToken
    }).exec((function(callback, err, results) {

        var deleteSuccess = results && results.deletedCount === 1;

        if (!deleteSuccess) {
            console.error('Token not deleted');
        }

        callback(err, deleteSuccess);
    }).bind(null, callback));
};
```

The revoke token is done but I am not understanding how to call this one? do I have to do something like this?

```
app.post('/logout', revokeToken);
```

Postman screenshot:

[image: Get token:]
[image: logout:]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [node-oauth2-server](https://github.com/oauthjs/node-oauth2-server) library, only [three APIs](https://github.com/oauthjs/node-oauth2-server/blob/master/docs/docs/getting-started.rst) call available.
it are oauth.authorize(), oauth.authenticate() and oauth.token(), there are no revoke_token() API but we can workaround to revoke token by refresh token().

This is my approaches by refresh token method.
Adding this code in [app.js](https://github.com/pedroetb/node-oauth2-server-mongo-example/blob/master/app.js) of [example](https://github.com/pedroetb/node-oauth2-server-mongo-example)

```
app.post('/logout', revokeToken, function(req, res) {
    res.send('Congratulations, you are logged out!');
});

function revokeToken(req, res) {
    var request = new Request(req);
    var response = new Response(res);
    return app.oauth.token(request, response)
        .then(function(token) {
            token.accessToken = '';
            token.accessTokenExpiresAt = '';
            token.refreshToken = '';
            token.refreshTokenExpiresAt = '';
            res.json(token);
        }).catch(function(err) {
            res.status(err.code || 500).json(err);
        });
}
```

#### Demo

#### 1. Run example

```
npm start
```

#### 2. Ready to assign to Postman variable

[image]

#### 3. Get Access token and Refresh Token

[image]

#### 4. Check Valid access token

[image]

#### 5. Logout - using refresh token and revoke the access token

[image]

#### 6. Check valid access token - access-token no more valid due to revoked by refresh token.

[image]